# How to find the maximum of $E(X)\cdot E(1/X)$?

Tags: probability, inequality

For $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$, with $0<x_1\le x_2\dots\leq x_n$, find the maximum of 
$$
\sum_k x_kp_k \sum_l \frac1{x_l}\, p_l, \quad \sum_k p_k =1, p_k\ge0
$$

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I can get the minimum is $1$. But I have no idea of the reverse direction. By estimating, $\sum_k x_k p_k\le x_n, \sum_k \frac1{x_k}p_k\le \frac1{x_1}$, but it is not the maximum.

The form of this question is the same as $E(X)E(1/X)$, with $X>0$, maybe it is interesting for the continuous case.

Any help is appreciated.

Find a proof at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141766/exe1-x-leq-a-b2-4ab

Comment: This is known as Kantorovich’s Inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no bound for $EX E\frac 1 X$. For example let $X$ take the values $1$ and $n$ with probability $\frac 1 2 $ each to make $EX E\frac 1 X$  go to $\infty$. However, it can be shown that if $0<a<X<b<\infty$ almost surely then $EX E\frac 1 X \leq \frac {(a+b)^{2}} {4ab}$.

Proof of above inequality:

Consider $x+\frac{ab}{x}$ on $[a,b]$. Since $a-\frac{ab}{x^{2}}>0$ when $x>%
\sqrt{ab}$ and $a-\frac{ab}{x^{2}}<0$ when $x<\sqrt{ab}$ ( and $\sqrt{ab}$ $%
\in $ $(a,b)$) the maximum value is attained when $x$ is $a$ or $b$. Hence $%
x+\frac{ab}{x}$ $\leq a+b$. Thus $X+\frac{ab}{X}\leq a+b$ and $EX+abE\frac 1
{X}\leq a+b$. By AM-GM inequality This implies $\sqrt{(EX)(abE\frac{1}{X})}\leq \frac{a+b}{2}$
so $EXE\frac{1}{X}\leq \frac{(a+b)^{2}}{4ab}$.

Comment: Where can I find a proof? Thanks!

Comment: @Yukinooo I have included a proof now.